# Rename "value" variable in set accessor of a property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

IN VB.NET you can change the name of this variable. Can you do this in C# too or is it always called `value`?

Example:

```vb
    Private _SomeVariable As String
    Public Property SomeValue() As String
        Get
            Return _SomeVariable
        End Get
        Set(ByVal foo As String) ' This is what I mean
            _SomeVariable = foo
        End Set
    End Property
```

I'm used to write code in VB.NET, but want to change to C# eventually and trying to learn all the differences and peculiarities of C#.

I know this is no big deal, but [Telerik](https://converter.telerik.com/) for example isn't aware of it while converting VB.NET to C#, which could lead to a missbehaviour in case you have a class variable named `foo` too (for the above-mentioned example).

Comment: Telerik probably didn't bother allowing for the parameter name being changed because they didn't expect anyone to be crazy enough to do it.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, you should read Anthony Green's "Exhausting list of differences between VB.NET and C#" here: https://anthonydgreen.net/2019/02/12/exhausting-list-of-differences-between-vb-net-c/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set parameter is always named `value`, and you cannot change it. If you happen to have a conflicting name in your code, you can use the fully-qualified name in order to use it:

```
class MyClass
{
    private string value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }  // this.value is the private field
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C#, the new value is *always* accessed via [`value`](https://thedeveloperblog.com/value). There is no syntax to write a setter to accept a custom name.

See [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties).

> The set accessor resembles a method whose return type is void. It uses an implicit parameter *called value*, whose type is the type of the property ..

Answer (score 0):

The `value` is keyword, so it cannot be changed